# php + ubuntu upgrade

Tags: php, apache, ubuntu, include

Just upgraded from Ubuntu 12.10 to Ubuntu 13.10
But left old php.ini and httpd.conf

And this is what I get now:

> `Fatal error: require_once(): Failed opening required 'serverConstants.php' (include_path='.:/usr/share/php:/www/allSites') in /www/myproject/src/lib/starter.php on line 12`

```
-rwxrwxrwx 1 www-data root 202 Jan 23  2013 /www/allSites/serverConstants.php
```

How is this even possible?

`/www` is mounted from host machine (Ubuntu runs in a VM) if that matters, but I did't have this problem before the upgrade

Answer (score 0):

Some servers (particularly on shared servers, but could be anywhere) forbid access to "world writable" files and directories, as a security measure. The first thing to try is changing the permissions on this file to 644 or even 444.

Comment: it's not the permissions. when I change it to absolute path ('/www/allSites/serverConstants.php'), everything works.